# Display images depending on a timer

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to display different images for a specific period of time. This is the code that im using but somehow it only displays the first image. Also i want to display a timer to show the time passed.

```
package imagedisplay;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
/**
 *
 * @author D
 */
public class ImageDisplay extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Image image1 = new Image("file:lib/1.jpg") ;
        Image image2 = new Image("file:lib/2.jpg")  ;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(

                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image1)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), image2)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(imageView.imageProperty(), null))
                );
        timeline.play();
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me, are you sure the images are what you think they are?

Comment: @user3272243 what do you mean by remove the images? They are using an imageView, and they set the image that is displayed. That seems like the 100% correct way to do it.

Comment: my bad, i had issues with netbeans.
So. how can i add timer 
and @user3272243 the point is to display all these images again together and decide which is the correct one.

Comment: @dailyadd To display all the images together, you will need 3 ImageView's.

Comment: im closing this thanks a lot guys

Comment: @TiyebBellal: The images do not seem to be resources ( -> `file:` protocol required) and for resources you'd better use `Class` / `ClassLoader` to get the url for resources right.